# Windows Command: how do I push current directory using chdir for popping later?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command

**Context/Objective:**

In windows 7, I'm developing a batch script using regular windows commands.  Within this batch, I need to save the current directory first thing so it can be restored when the script finishes running.

**What I have tried so for:**

I've attempted to use commands of chdir, pushd and popd to make it work.

- Try 1:

  PUSHD CHDIR

  REM main script body

  POPD

  **Result:** error on PUSHD line "the system cannot find the path specified"
- Try 2:

  SET curdir=CHDIR

  PUSHD %curdir%

  REM main script body

  POPD

  **Result:** same error on PUSHD line "the system cannot find the path specified"
- Other tries: Also googling didn't yield any satisfactory results.

**The Questions:**

Can I make it work using these commands?
Or is there another set of commands that I need to use?

**Note:I'm looking for a solution using windows native commands only, third party tools or powershell is not an option.**

Comment: `pushd` most likely fails because it can't find the directory that you provided as an argument.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `.` to represent the current diretory.

Try this:

```
PUSHD .

REM The rest of you script

POPD
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  The official documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd states that the `Path` argument is optional, and is described as `Specifies the directory to make the current directory`, meaning that it doesn't affect how the directory stack is manipulated, meaning `pushd` would be the same as `pushd .`.  But this is false.  The documentation is unclear and/or wrong.

Comment: PUSHD combines pushing the current directory onto the stack and changing to the specified directory, all in one operation. So I consider this the more correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you need to use the `CD` command (instead of CHDIR) and don't forget to wrap it in %'s.. It is common to think they are they same, but they do differ, slightly, in this way.

Try the following example in a batch file:

```
@echo off

echo Initial directory set to:
cd "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
echo   `%cd%`
echo.

pushd %CD%

echo Changing to %AppData%
REM main script body
cd /D %AppData%
echo   `%cd%`
echo.

echo Changing to %LocalAppData%
cd /D %LocalAppData%
echo   `%cd%`
echo.

echo.
echo About to POPD
pause
POPD
echo   `%cd%`
echo.
```

I should note the @aphoria's answer is just as valid.

Comment: Minor nitpick...you are not using the `CD` command, but rather the `CD` environment variable, which is referenced by wrapping it in `%` characters (`%CD%`).

Answer (score 4):

Working solutions by both @aphoria and @wasatchwizard.  Wish I could mark both as answers.  Thank you both!

I'm consolidating them into one for those who will run into the same questions.

Option 1:

```
PUSHD .
REM main scripts body
POPD
```

Option 2:

```
PUSHD %cd%
REM main scripts body
POPD
```